# In BigQuery, shuffle values in one column based on sequential ordering of another column

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select 't1' as team, 'tom' as name, 1 as value, 1 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'joe' as name, 5 as value, 2 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'sal' as name, 4 as value, 3 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'chi' as name, 9 as value, 4 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'nik' as name, 7 as value, 5 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'bil' as name, 6 as value, 6
```

We are not looking to perform an ordinary `order by` operation, but rather we are looking to shuffle around the values in the `value` column based on the values in the `rk` column. The row with the lowest `rk` gets the lowest value. Although there is only 1 unique value in the `team` column, in our full dataset we'd like to partition by `team`. The objective output for this sample data would then be:

```
select 't1' as team, 'tom' as name, 1 as value, 1 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'joe' as name, 4 as value, 2 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'sal' as name, 5 as value, 3 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'chi' as name, 6 as value, 4 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'nik' as name, 7 as value, 5 as rk union all
select 't1' as team, 'bil' as name, 9 as value, 6
```

... where the values in `value` are now ascending in conjunction with the `rk` column. We can safely assume there will be no duplicate values within each `team` partition in either the `value` or the `rk` columns. We've tried using a window function as such:

```
select 
  *
  ,any_value(value) over(partition by team order by rk) as newValue
from t1
```

but this does not sort the column as we hoped / at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select t.* replace(arr[offset(rk - 1)] as value)
from your_table t
join (
  select team, array_agg(value order by value) arr
  from your_table
  group by team
)
using(team)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]